# Find the order of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

> Given  $A = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} a &b \\  0 & a\end{bmatrix} : a \neq 0 \right\} \subset \mathbb{GL}_2(\mathbb{F_3})$. Find  the  order of $A$ ?

My attempt  : Here number  of distinct non zero entries in $ A$ is  $2$  so  i thinks dim($A$) = order of $A= 2$

Is its correct ?

Comment: According to what you've written, $A$ is a **subset** of $\mathbb{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$, not an element, you should fix your notation.

Comment: yes u r  correct@AryamanMaithani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a$ can be $2$ possible elements, $b$ can be $3$ so the order of $A$ is $6$. Recall that the order of the group is just the number of elements.

Comment: Good  logic @Henno sir  i missed that  logics   ..thanks  u sir